# Is there a comprehensive list(s) which has every single attribute/trait of G-d, blessed be He, with their corresponding Torah, Talmud, etc. verses?

Tags: sources-mekorot, theology, thirteen-attributes

As the question states, I'm looking for some kind of a resource which contains a clear list, in a bullet-point form or otherwise, of every single attribute of G-d, blessed be He, according to Jewish views (doesn't have to be only a single list). The most important part is that there are corresponding quotes from the Torah, **Talmud**, etc. (most of these lists only focus on the Hebrew Bible, but not necessarily on the way G-d, blessed be He, and His attributes are described in the Talmud, for instance).

To give an example:

- All-knowing (Torah verse citation)
- All-powerful (Torah verse citation)
- Just (Torah verse citation)
- and so on.

I hope someone has made such a list before. Its okay if there are multiple lists which are fragmented, as long as the combination of such lists is truly exhaustive and comprehensive.

Comment: Introduction to the delicate philosophy of Hashem's attributes: https://www.sefaria.org/Duties_of_the_Heart%2C_First_Treatise_on_Unity.10.1?lang=bi&with=Commentary%20ConnectionsList&lang2=en. It does contain many but is not complete. Just want to put it here because of the delicacy of the question

Comment: @RabbiKaii Thank you, I'll take a look